# Validating contact form with javascript

Tags: javascript

The code below obviously has a lot of errors or some other things missing but I am beginner to JavaScript trying to make my own projects.

I tried to make this contact form with JavaScript validation from my own and a bit with a search but I'm stuck because validation form doesn't work at all. I would appreciate if you help me fixing this, thank you.

```js
let name = document.querySelector('.name');
let email = document.querySelector('.email');
let submit = document.querySelector('.submit');

function validateName() {
  if (name === null) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Name cannot be blank';
    return false;
  } else if (name < characters.length < 3) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Use more than 3 characters';
    return false;
  }
}

function validateEmail() {
  if (email === null) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Email cannot be blank';
    return false;
  } else if (email < characters.length < 5) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Use more than 3 characters on email';
    return false;
  }
}

function submitForm() {
  document.querySelector('.submit').submit();
}
```

```css
.info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: mediumslateblue;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.name {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.email {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.mesage {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.submit {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div class="info-form">
    <input class="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name">
    <br>
    <input class="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email">
    <br>
    <textarea name="message" class="mesage" cols="36" rows="3" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button class="submit" action="/submit.php" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Based on the code you provided it looks like you may have forgotten to define `characters`. It would be helpful to post what error messages you are seeing, if any, and what the expected outcome of your function is vs. what you are actually seeing.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mjs28k

Comment: There is no function for querySelector() called submit(). I don't know where you got this function call for submit() from.

Comment: There is also no 'action' attribute for <button>s. The 'action' attribute is usually for forms.

Comment: yeah i was missing a lot of functions finally they solved it for me, but about attribute i can say that since i have started learning javascript 2 months ago i keep forgeting even basic stuffs because i mostly try to practice javascript lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you only defined validation methods but don't use them, that's why they have no effect.

You should add event listeners like `onchange` (or `oninput`, depending on when you'd like to show error messages) to your fields.

For instance:

```
<input class="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" onchange="validateName()">
```

Actually, you have multiple more problems:

- `error` is undefined: you should create another element and find it in JS
- you have to use `element.value`, not `element` to access a value of input
- you have undefined `characters` used in a weird way in your checks; to check the length of content, use `element.value.length`

Here's a snippet with these fixes:

```js
let name = document.querySelector('.name');
let email = document.querySelector('.email');
let submit = document.querySelector('.submit');
let error = document.querySelector('.error');

function validateName() {
  if (!name.value) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Name cannot be blank';
    return false;
  } else if (name.value.length < 3) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Use more than 3 characters';
    return false;
  }
}

function validateEmail() {
  if (!email.value) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Email cannot be blank';
    return false;
  } else if (email.value.length < 5) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Use more than 3 characters on email';
    return false;
  }
}

function submitForm() {
  document.querySelector('.submit').submit();
}
```

```css
.info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: mediumslateblue;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.name {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.email {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.mesage {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.submit {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div class="info-form">
    <input class="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" onchange="validateName()">
    <br>
    <input class="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email" onchange="validateEmail()">
    <br>
    <textarea name="message" class="mesage" cols="36" rows="3" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
    <div class="error"></div>
    <br>
    <button class="submit" action="/submit.php" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Moreover, I'd make some more improvements to the code, namely

- use `event.target` inside event handlers instead of calcing the elements globally (note the difference in usage inside html too);
- clear the error div when the content is ok!
- why multiple `return false` instead of one in the end of the handler?
- you don't use the `submit` variable, get rid of it; does `submitForm` do anything useful? (submits on submit??) Not sure, but it seems it should be removed, too

```js
let error = document.querySelector('.error');

function validateName(event) {
  let name = event.target;
  if (!name.value) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Name cannot be blank';
  } else if (name.value.length < 3) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Use more than 3 characters';
  } else {
    error.innerHTML = '';
  }
  return false;
}

function validateEmail(event) {
  let email = event.target;
  if (!email.value) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Email cannot be blank';
  } else if (email.value.length < 5) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Use more than 3 characters on email';
  } else {
    error.innerHTML = '';
  }
  return false;
}

function submitForm() {
  document.querySelector('.submit').submit();
}
```

```css
.info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: mediumslateblue;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.name {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.email {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.mesage {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.submit {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div class="info-form">
    <input class="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" onchange="validateName(event)">
    <br>
    <input class="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email" onchange="validateEmail(event)">
    <br>
    <textarea name="message" class="mesage" cols="36" rows="3" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
    <div class="error"></div>
    <br>
    <button class="submit" action="/submit.php" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i didn't knew i can add return false at the end of the function line so i don't have to name it after if or else just learnt it now, thank you again for help man :)

Comment: btw if you click submit button why doesn't send me to submit.php as i have added on html file, but it just stays on that page still or i am wrong?

Comment: @Behar are you trying to submit it here or on your site? Have you checked what browser console says? (can you share the link to the page?)

Comment: https://codepen.io/beh4r/pen/Zwojvp
This same code i use on my laptop and doesn't show any error when i click submit everything looks fine and i have added action="/submit.php"  on html file

Comment: @Behar submit.php should be a separate *file* and if it is referenced as `/submit.php`, it should be in the root folder of your site (`example.com/submit.php`). In some cases, you may want it to be in the same folder as the html discussed (say, `example.com/register/index.html` and `example.com/register/submit.php`), in that case you should reference it as `./submit.php`. Now, you can't upload a php file one codepen :) so your submit button won't do a thing (unless you put some *feedback* logic into `submitForm`), actual submitting should be to a php script which you have to create

Answer (score 2):

Alot of your syntax and validation methods are off. Few tips: you need to use `name.value` and `email.value` to get the values of the elements, you also need to use `name.value.length` instead of `email < characters.length < 5` and change the button type to submit and you can negate having to call it in JS.

Below is a **working snippet** based on the code you posted. I believe it does what you want.

```js
let error = document.getElementById('error');

function validateName() {
let name = document.getElementById('name');
  if (!name.value) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Name cannot be blank';
    return false;
  } else if (name.value.length < 3) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Use more than 3 characters on name';
    return false;
  }
}

function validateEmail() {
let email = document.getElementById('email');
  if (!email.value) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Email cannot be blank';
    return false;
  } else if (email.value.length < 5) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Use more than 5 characters on email';
    return false;
  }
}

function submitForm() {
  error.innerHTML = ""
  validateEmail()
  validateName()
}
```

```css
.info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: mediumslateblue;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.name {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.email {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.mesage {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.submit {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div class="info-form">
    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name">
    <br>
    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email">
    <br>
    <textarea name="message" class="mesage" cols="36" rows="3" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button class="submit" type = "submit" action="/submit.php" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
    <div id="error">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah this one works well thank you but a question, why it doesn't show the error when i type less than 3 characters on name or email, but it shows error when i leave those fields blank ?

Comment: If you run the snippet above it should also display an error when you type less than 3 characters in the name or email input field. I'm not quite sure what you're referencing.

Comment: yeah it was showing an error but i was trying on my pc and forgot to change email < value.length < 5 to email.value.length < 5 and that was the reason why it didn't worked

Comment: another question: if you try to add more than 3 characters on email field, it still says add 3 or more characters even it has 4 or 5, so it works if i add about 7 or 8 ?

Comment: The email is checking to see if you have less than 5 characters while name is just checking for 3. There was just a typo in the error statement indicating you need more than 3 characters when you really need more than 5 for email. I edited my snipped with the correction.

Answer (score 1):

You've written your JS function validateName and validateEmails but you aren't calling those functions anywhere. Instead of selecting the .submit button inside of submitForm(), call those functions. The line you have inside of submitForm is doing nothing. onclick() within your HTML handles the calling of the function submitForm(), and submitForm() should then validate your form.

Edit: you can also call validateName and validateEmails when the email or name fields are edited.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, like what the other contributors said, the validate functions are written well, they just aren't being called.

You can either add them to the `onchange` property of your input elements, or call it in your `submitform` function like so:

```
function validateName() {
    if (name === null) {
        error.innerHTML = 'Name cannot be blank';
        return false;
    } else if (name < characters.length < 3) {
        error.innerHTML = 'Use more than 3 characters';
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
function validateEmail() {
    if (email === null) {
        error.innerHTML = 'Email cannot be blank';
        return false;
    } else if (email < characters.length < 5) {
        error.innerHTML = 'Use more than 3 characters on email';
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function submitForm(){
    if(validateName() && validateEmail()){
      //Do whatever submitting entails
    }
}
```

Also remember to add an error div to your html to display the errors, and to create an error querySelector variable like you did with name, email and submit.

You're doing great! Keep up the good work!

Comment: yeah i was missing validateforms() on html text aswell,
and about div you were right and i thought it would show with innerHTML so no need to add div too but i was wrong lol, thank you man :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that works to a minimum using your current code. I added comments to explain what is going on. Don't hesitate to ask me for any clarifications. Like you said, code can be improved further but I didn't want to change too much and confuse you.

```js
let name = document.querySelector('.name');
let email = document.querySelector('.email');
let submit = document.querySelector('.submit');
let error = document.querySelector('#error'); //Get's the span in the html where the errors will be shown.

function validateName() {
  //Get the text value of name with name.value and care with an empty string.
  if (name.value === "") {
    error.innerHTML = 'Name cannot be blank';
    return false;
    //Get the number of character in the value of the name and see if you have less than 3.
  } else if (name.value.length < 3) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Use more than 3 characters';
    return false;
  }
}

function validateEmail() {
//Get the text value of name with name.value and compare with an empty string.
  if (email.value === "") {
    error.innerHTML = 'Email cannot be blank';
    return false;
    //Get the number of characters in the value of the email and see if you have less than 5.
  } else if (email.value.length < 5) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Use more than 3 characters on email';
    return false;
  }
}

function submitForm() {
//Instead of calling the function .submit (that doesn't exist). Call the verification functions that you made.
  validateName();
  validateEmail();
}
```

```css
.info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: mediumslateblue;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.name {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.email {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.mesage {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.submit {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div class="info-form">
    <span id="error"></span>
    <input class="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name">
    <br>
    <input class="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email">
    <br>
    <textarea name="message" class="mesage" cols="36" rows="3" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button class="submit" action="/submit.php" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah this one works great but there's an error what it says Email cannot be blank I write the email but it stays still Email cannot be blank any idea?

Comment: @Behar so you want the error message to be removed when you type in the input? You can add an event listeners on your inputs to remove the errors after you start typing. 'input.addEventListener('input', function()
{
    error.value = "";
});'